# google chrome headless repl doen't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webbrowser-control, headless-browser, google-chrome-headless

I'm running this command

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --enable-logging --repl https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

then I get a cmd filled with the error

```
{"result":{"type":"undefined"}}
```

my os is windows 8.1
chrome version 63.0.3239.84

Comment: isn't there any help